# customized jQuery mobile datebox according to database values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, calendar

I have a mobile application with MVC.NET, MySQL, jQuery Mobile. I need a customized datebox (jQuery Mobile) according to some values from a database table.

For example, I need some days, from the datebox, to be colored in green, others in gray, others in red or white (depending on the values from table).

It's this possible?

DateBox code:

```
@Html.Label("Date:  *")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @Class = "calendar", @data_icon = "false", @type = "text", data_role = "datebox", data_options = "{\"mode\":\"calbox\",\"useNewStyle\": true,\"overrideStyleClass\": \"calendar\",\"fieldsOrderOverride\": [\"d\",\"m\",\"y\"],\"headerFormat\":\"%A,%d, %-m, %Y\",\"dateFormat\":\"DD-MM-YYYY\",\"useTodayButton\":true}" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
```

Comment: You mean [this DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with the DateBox code.

Comment: I think that I should do a Jquery function to change the .css class for 'div.ui-datebox-griddate', but I don't know how to do with database query.

Comment: Then setup a server that you can send an AJAX request to. The server executes the MySQL and returns the 'special' dates. Or if this page is generated from the server, you can directly insert the dates into the page without doing a request.